# Add different types of cells to UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an UITableView in the menu of my application. This table has at the beginning a specific number of cells (rows).

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 5;
}
```

When for example the cell having the `indexPath.row = 1` is clicked, I must Add some new cells (lets say 3 cells) after this cell (so in the index 2, 3 and 4). And when this cell is clicked for the second time, I must remove the added cells. The problem is that the cells to add has a different type (another class). I searched about how to add/remove cells and I found that I can use the `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` and the delete one. But how can I specify the type of the cell then return it? 
This is the button target of my cell:

```
 [cell.showDetail addTarget:self action:@selector(btnSowDetailClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I don't know what to put in the selector to do what I describe:

```
-(void) btnSowDetailClicked {
    // ????
}
```

And how can I set the `numberOfRowsInSection` in the selector?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to keep track of if you aren't already -

1. the state of the button
2. a data source for the class of the cell to return
3. the number of cells

One suggestion is to manage an **NSMutableArray** of **NSStrings** (which represent the cell class to return)

In the button action do the following where **NSStrings** represent the cell class for a particular index (e.g. @"UITableViewCell" or @"MyCustomCell" etc ) -

```
-(void) btnSowDetailClicked {
    // Toggle button state - prob better to persist in property BOOL cellButtonState
    cellButtonState = !cellButtonState;
    // update data source(s) accordingly
     if (cellButton.selected) {
          // add NSStrings to data source array
          // create array of NSIndexPaths to pass to table view
          // update UITableView with - (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
     }
     else {
          // remove NSStrings from data source array
          // create array of NSIndexPaths to pass to table view
          // update UITableView with - deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
     }
}
```

As stated in the documentation about the above **UITableView** methods -

> **UITableView** calls the relevant delegate and data source methods immediately afterward to get the cells and other content for visible cells.

So the datasource can return **[dataSourceArray count]** for number of rows. To get the correct class for where you return the cell, in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** grab the **NSString** object from the data source array at indexPath.row and use **NSClassFromString** to get the class for the cell!

Answer (score -1):

you can init an mutablearray to store your cells,  no matter how many of your cell's type, when you need to add a cell, init and store it to the array.

in the `numberOfRows` method , just `return array.count;`

in the `cellforrowatindexpath` method, get the cell from your array, then return the cell.